# Scala - Update mutable maps inside immutable Vector

Tags: scala, dictionary, vector

I'm trying to build a Vector[Map[String, Any]] in Scala. I know that Vector is immutable, and I'm using mutable Map.

When I try to do this:

```
def calculate_objectives(pop: Vector[Map[String, Any]]): Unit ={
  for (i <- 0 until pop_size){
    pop(i) = pop(i) + ("weights" -> decode(pop(i)("genome").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]]))
    pop(i) = pop(i) + ("objective" -> Vector(objective1(pop(i)("weights").asInstanceOf[Vector[Float]]), objective2(pop(i)("weights").asInstanceOf[Vector[Float]])))
  }
}
```

I'm not trying to change the Vector, just the Map inside the Vector. Is this possible?

I get two equal errors when I try to compile this code, I was wondering if this is the problem.

```
Error:(102, 7) value update is not a member of Vector[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Any]]
  pop(i) = pop(i) + ("weights" -> decode(pop(i)("genome").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `Map` is [defined in `Predef` as `scala.collection.immutable.Map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#Map[A,+B]=scala.collection.immutable.Map[A,B]).

If you want a vector with mutable maps, then you have to declare the type explicitly as `collection.mutable.Map`, and then you have to `update` the map, not the vector:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MutMap}

def calculate_objectives(pop: Vector[MutMap[String, Any]]): Unit = {
  for (i <- 0 until pop.size){
    pop(i)("weights") = decode(pop(i)("genome").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]])
    pop(i)("objective") = Vector(
      objective1(pop(i)("weights").asInstanceOf[Vector[Float]]), 
      objective2(pop(i)("weights").asInstanceOf[Vector[Float]])
    )
  }
}
```

Here I used renaming import that renames `collection.mutable.Map` to `MutMap`. If you want, you can write out the fully qualified name `collection.mutable.Map` in the type of `pop`.

Comment: That what I was trying to do. I knew that Map needed to be mutable, and that was already done. But obviously, I was updating the Map in the wrong way. Thank you very much!

Comment: @flyist you probably mean *"I knew that Map needed to be mutable"*, otherwise you couldn't update anything in-place.